# Dictionary Unique Keys Rename and Replace

Tags: pandas, dictionary, replace, unique

I have a dictionary format structure like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
'CODES' : [{"1407273790":5,"1801032636":20,"1174813554":1,"1215470448":2,"1053754655":4,"1891751228":1},
{"1497066526":19,"1801032636":16,"1215470448":11,"1891751228":18},
{"1215470448":8,"1407273790":4},]})
```

Now I want to create a unique list of keys and create names for them like this -

```
np_code     np_rename
1407273790  np_1
1801032636  np_2
1174813554  np_3
1215470448  np_4
1053754655  np_5
1891751228  np_6
1497066526  np_7
```

And finally replace the new names in main dataframe df -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
'CODES' : [{"np_1":5,"np_2":20,"np_3":1,"np_4":2,"np_5":4,"np_6":1},
{"np_7":19,"1801032636":16,"np_4":11,"np_6":18},
{"np_4":8,"np_1":4},]})
```

Comment: How do you know that ID "A" gets `np_1` and ID "C" gets `np_8` for the same np_code i.e 1407273790

Comment: sorry I edited the code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use apply here:

Assuming the unique list dataframe is `unique_list_df`:

```
u = df['CODES'].map(lambda x: [*x.keys()]).explode().unique()
d = dict(zip(u,'np_'+pd.Index((pd.factorize(u)[0]+1).astype(str))))

f = lambda x: {d.get(k,k): v for k,v in x.items()}
df['CODES'] = df['CODES'].apply(f)
```

---

```
print(df)

  ID                                              CODES
0  A  {'np_1': 5, 'np_2': 20, 'np_3': 1, 'np_4': 2, ...
1  B   {'np_7': 19, 'np_2': 16, 'np_4': 11, 'np_6': 18}
2  C                             {'np_4': 8, 'np_1': 4}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. How do I get the unique list? I used this n_value = set( name for dic in df for name in dic.keys()) and this throws up error.

Comment: @Santoo in your question the unique list looks like a dataframe? I have defined the same as `unique_list_df` and then you can use the same code as mine to create `d`

Comment: yes it is a dataframe. my question was how do I get the unique list of keys from the df?

Comment: @Santoo Sorry I didnot follow you. Did you mean you also want to create that unique dataframe dynamically? Currently the question looks like you have 2 dfs, one being the original one and another the unique list dataframe

Comment: sorry from the df above, how do I create a unique list of keys? i.e how do I create unique_list_df? I can add np_rename but how do I get np_code?

Comment: @Santoo Edited my answer with the unique dictionary